# Injecting HTML5 Canvas animations etc into existing wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, canvas, swiffy

Wanting some advice on how to add canvas animation (created with Animate CC - RIP Flash or with Swiffy) into an exisiting wordpress theme where you are restricted from play with the PHP. Is there a plugin, widget or best practice for doing this?

Thanks for your patience...

Comment: See: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/html5canvas-background